# Sharepoint Caml

Tags: php, sharepoint, list, caml

I am using php and caml to retrieve a list from sharepoint, only it seems to bring back a minimal list, I am wondering how to set the list view to show all list items, rather than the default minimal list. I am in noway an expert in sharepoint and this is the first time I have used caml so forgive my noobness on the subject.

here is my query

```
<GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">  
          <listName>'.$list.'</listName> 
          <rowLimit>'.$limit.'</rowLimit>
          '.$queryXML.'
          <queryOptions xmlns:SOAPSDK9="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" >              
              <QueryOptions/> 
          </queryOptions> 
        </GetListItems>'
```

I fill out the list and limit variables and it brings back the default list view from sharepoint, but I want to add either the ability to just bring back everything in the list or tell it which columns  to bring back, but I'm having little to no luck searching this on the internet :(

Thanks in advance for your replies

Answer (score 3):

You should start by checking the documentation of the web service method at [List.GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx). You need to supply the ViewFields parameter with the fields you want to return.

Creating CAML queries is not for the faint of heart. There are a lot of discrepancies and the language is used for many unrelated tasks. Executing a CAML query from the native object model is slightly different than calling a web service. Luckily, U2U has created [CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) which allows you to create CAML queries by selecting the method you want to connect (Web Services in your case), the list, fields, filtering and ordering criteria you need.

If you target SharePoint 2010 you may want to avoid the (venerable) web services and use the REST/OData API. [OData](http://radar.oreilly.com/2011/04/uniform-apis-odata.html) is an API similar to GData for accessing various data sources that allows easy filtering, selection and best of all, is uniform for all data sources. You can call the REST API directly from your code or you can use the [OData SDK for PHP](http://odataphp.codeplex.com/) to generate a proxy class for your list that will allow you to execute queries in a very simple way.

Check the "[Introduction to querying lists with REST](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/01/21/introduction-to-querying-lists-with-rest-and-listdata-svc-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)" for a nice introduction to the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SP 2013 or 2010?  If it's 2013, I would recommend using the Rest services for SP.  It's a lot easier to use and you don't have to use that crazy CAML.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the list settings on SharePoint and set Item Limit which is responsible for displaying certain amount of records. If you do not specify view name, then the default view is used. If this default view is set to display item in batches or display limited number of items then you will only fetch that number of records. This is all to be set in list/library settings via UI. If you do specify CAML query along with all options then the view is ignored and you will get all the records returned by CAML query. Here's an example defining new CAML query (in C# though), where view ID is used (between curly braces) and in addition a CAML query is provided. This narrows results fetched from that view. You can easily google for how to find list ID.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
XmlNode ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");
ndQueryOptions.InnerXml = "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>" + "<DateInUtc>FALSE</DateInUtc>";
XmlNode ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
ndQuery.InnerXml = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='LinkTitle'/><Value Type='Text'>New Tasks</Value></Eq></Where>";
XmlNode confNode = listsSvc.GetListItems("NotificationConfig", "{92428C7A-3F35-41B2-AEC4-B8B1C7E64533}", ndQuery, null, null, ndQueryOptions, null);
```